# How does one configure a temporary exception to ATS on El Capitan and fix webkit2png?

Tags: macos

```
[16:46] webkit2png http://www.google.com
Fetching http://www.google.com ...
2015-10-12 16:47:05.644 Python[34891:1646785] App Transport Security has
blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure.
Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
... something went wrong: The resource could not be loaded because the App
Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

How/where does one configure a temporary exception to use webkit2png with ATS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code edit posted [here](https://github.com/bendalton/webkit2png/commit/9a96ac8977c386a84edb674ca1518e90452cee88) allows for use of non-https domains under El Capitan. Edit code as specified. `webkit2png --ignore-ssl-check [options] [http://example/]` for desired result. Good luck.